# How to override "downlod multiple files" popup

Tags: ruby, selenium-chromedriver, watir

I use watir for browser automation. I have a popup that shows "Download multiple files" that needs to be clicked before the file downloads. How can i override this?
i have tried all the settings correctly but its no good.

> I use chrome  chrome=88.0.4324.150

```
    download_dir = "#{Dir.pwd}/downloads".gsub('/', '\\')
Dir.mkdir download_dir unless Dir.exist? download_dir
args     = %w(--disable-infobars)
prefs    = { download: { prompt_for_download: false, default_directory: download_dir }}

       

  ie=Watir::Browser.new(:chrome, options: { args: args }, prefs: prefs)
```

I did some further comparision. the default chrome on my machine allows multiple downloads but the ones launched by watir does not. How do i fix it?
[image]

[image]

Comment: The difference is in profile. So load the same profile. Or create the profile with this switch off and load thar profile.

Comment: how can i load the profile via Watir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
prefs = {'profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads' => 2}
Watir::Browser.new(:chrome, options: {prefs: prefs})
```

1. Watir Capabilities are not in the best place, so this isn't as straightforward as would be nice. It will get fixed in Watir 7, which will be based on Selenium 4
2. Using Selenium Capabilities class is not converting correctly to w3c syntax, just the old JSON Wire Protocol syntax, which isn't helpful
3. Selenium 3 code is converting by default everything that is a `Symbol` from snake case to camel case. So the key has to be a `String`. Selenium 4 fixes that specifically for Chrome prefs.
4. The correct pref for turning off that toggle is "profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads"
5. For these preferences, 0 is default, 1 is enabled & 2 is disabled. Except it doesn't seem to matter which value is passed in; if you pass in anything it seems to toggle that setting off. /shrug

Answer (score 0):

I am using `puppeteer-extra` to download multiple images from website, that `allow-multiple-download` browser popup was stopping me from download multiple images.
I manage to fix this using `puppeteer-extra-plugin-user-preferences` plugin.
the `automatic-downloads` option in fix this issue.

```js
puppeteer.use(
  UserPreferencesPlugin({
    userPrefs: {
      download: {
        prompt_for_download: false,
        open_pdf_in_system_reader: true,
        default_directory: downloadImageDirectoryPath,
        automatic_downloads: 1,
      },
      plugins: {
        always_open_pdf_externally: true,
      },
    },
  })
);
```

**Update:** above snippet was unreliable(it works sometime other time it cause the issue)
here is another snippet that worked for me, no issues for far.

```js
puppeteer.use(
  UserPreferencesPlugin({
    userPrefs: {
      download: {
        prompt_for_download: false,
        open_pdf_in_system_reader: true,
        default_directory: downloadImageDirectoryPath,
        // automatic_downloads: 1,
      },
      plugins: {
        always_open_pdf_externally: true,
      },
      // disable allow-multiple-downloads popup
      profile: {
        default_content_setting_values: {
          automatic_downloads: 1,
        },
      },
    },
  })
);
```